# Unable to access static files in Django - Development server

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to access static files in browser but unable to access them. My static settings in`settings.py` are below

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', FrontPage.as_view()),
    # url('', include(router.urls))
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My folder structure

```
projectname
       projectname
             settings.py
             urls.py
       app1_name
       static
             bs4
                  css
                     cover.css
             admin
       templates
```

My `template.html`

```
<link href="/static/bs4/css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The above link isn't loading the static file. I'm getting 404 on hitting above url. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

[image]

Comment: use `{% static 'css/bootstrap/css/cover.css' %}`

Comment: @Rakesh I am getting 404 on this url --> `http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/cover.css`

Comment: @Rakesh if i keep my `static files directory` outside my django_project and add it in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` then i am able to access static files. Why is that so ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem; I'ii update my answer

Comment: Yes, It seems that the server is looking for .css file in another directory. when you set : STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), the server will searchin the right directory, and then you can set STATICFILES_DIRS to the right one

Answer (score 2):

All you need is an update of your settings:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
```

Comment: the linking you have suggested is more generic but from the browser i should be able to access the file at : `http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/cover.css` I am getting 404.   
Surprisingly, I am able to access css files of admin/ folder[see my director structure] which is at the same location.  Maybe some problems with my `settings.py`

Comment: Can you please share the error message displayed by your browser

Comment: added in the question body. It says 404 page not found.

Comment: The server finds 'static' directory. But can't find a bs4/css/cover.css file

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: copy you bootstarp directory and rename it by bs4

Comment: its already named `bs4` when i posted to SO i used the name `bootstrap`

Comment: if i keep my `static files directory` outside my django_project and add it in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` then i am able to access static files. Why is that so ?

Comment: this works. But tell me       

a) Don't i have to add this line `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) ` in `urls.py` ?        

b) Don't i have to add `STATIC_ROOT` variable in `settings.py` ?

Comment: a) I don't think it's a good Idea. In developpement mode, no problem. But in production mode you don't need staic files to be accessible. b) Yes you have, you'll need it in Production mode, when you'll  run ***python manage.py collectstatic*** all yous static files will be copied in STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Please, if you find this answer useful, accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use: `<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/cover.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Make sure to use `{% load static %}` at the top of your template.html and you are all set.